# How to get multiple data from select item in jquery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I am trying to get multiple value from multiple select `textbox` and use the same value in `PHP` for adding the SUM.

**My code is:**

```js
function get_amount() {
  var x = $('#work').val();;
  alert(x);
  $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "get-sum.php",
    data: 'id=' + x,
    success: function(data) {
      alert(data);
      //$('#html').load(document.URL +  ' #html');
    }
  });
}
```

```html
<select class="select2 select2-multiple" multiple="multiple" data-placeholder="Choose" name="work[]" id="work" onchange="get_amount()">
 <option value="1" >option 1</option>
 <option value="2"> OPtion 2 </option>
 <option value="3"> OPtion 3</option>
 </select>
```

And My php file as :

```
$id = $_POST['id'];


function getAmount($id){
global $mysqli;
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT
(amount)
FROM work
WHERE id = ?
");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($amount);
$stmt->store_result();
$stmt->fetch();
$stmt->close();
return $amount;
 }

$sql = getAmount($id);
echo $sql;
```

Error which i am getting is the data which i am getting from multiple select is like  5,6,7  and its always hitting the `php` file at id 5. And the second problem how i will be able to add all `$sql` data.

Comment: you can sum on the client and send only total to php

Answer (score 0):

I have done some changes in my PHP code :

```
$id = $_POST['id'];
$sum = 0;
for($i = 0; $i<count($id); $i++) {
  $sum = $sum + getAmount($id[$i]);
 }
echo $sum;

function getAmount(&$id){
global $mysqli;
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("SELECT SUM(amount) AS total FROM work WHERE id = (?)");
$stmt->bind_param("s",$id);
$stmt->execute();
$stmt->bind_result($amount);
$stmt->fetch();
return $amount['total'];
}
```